# User Defined Assignment

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on an assignment building an user defined function. When I run this select statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM DPSupervisorLookup('112233')
```

it gives me this error

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1 String or binary data would be
>   truncated.

I know that this particular employee ID is not in the data base but when I run one that does I am still getting the same error. Here is my code just in case I have a mistake somewhere.

```
Create Function DPSupervisorLookUp (@EmployeeID int)
Returns @Supervisors Table
(SupervisorEmployeeID Int,
SupervisorLastName Varchar(20),
SupervisorFirstName Varchar (20), 
SupervisorJobTitle Varchar(20))

As
begin
insert @Supervisors
select Distinct E2.EmployeeID as SupervisorEmployeeID, e2.LastName as     SupervisorLastName, E2.Firstname as SupervidorFirstName, E2.JobTitle as SupervisorJobTitle
from Employee e1
left outer join Employee e2 on e1.Supervisor = e2.EmployeeID

Return 
end
```

Comment: Show the `Employee` table definition. Also why you pass int as varchar and where are you use it?

Comment: Two questions.  1. Why are you passing in EmployeeID and not using it?  2.  Why are you passing in a string value to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of `LastName`, `Firstname` or `JobTitle` have length more than 20 char. Refer to `Employee` table scheme and create the `@Supervisors` table fields with appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

the columns size of @Supervisors should be equal Employee table

e.g
if size of Employee.LastName is 50 then size of  @Supervisors.SupervisorLastName should be 50 too